# Inverse Fourier Transform of | cos[(2 pi f)/100)] |

Tags: fourier-analysis

I would like a help calculating the Inverse Fourier Transform of

```
Absolute cos[(2 pi f)/100]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide the code that you have tried and found not to work well.

Comment: InverseFourierTransform [Abs[cos(\[Omega]/100)], \[Omega], t, FourierParameters -> {0, -2pi}]

Comment: The integral do not converge.  There is no Inverse. The function $f(t)$ must satisfy $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |f(t)| < \infty$ to have an inverse Fourier

Comment: That means that X(f)= | cos[(2 pi/100)*f} | can't be transformed to x(t) ?

Comment: @Nick The result will be a distribution. The only representation I can think of is a series of delta functions with some coefficients.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Vk7Az.gif

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/IIZ5d.jpg
I also made that calculations.Are they correct?

Comment: Based on the images you posted, it appears that your question belongs on [math.se], which deals with mathematics.  The present site deals with Mathematica software.

Comment: @bbgodfrey
I guess you are 100% right ..but i was puzzled why i couldn't run it on Mathematica.
Since I am here and compared to the (zero) responses i get from Mathematics section any help (off the record) would be appreciated .

Comment: This problem definitely is solvable, both analytically and with Mathematica, but `InverseFourierTransform[Abs[Cos[Omega/100]], Omega, t, FourierParameters -> {0, -2 Pi}]` is not sufficient.  I shall investigate a few other options when I have time.

Comment: Thank you very much...and it seams so easy...
$X(f)= | cos [(2 π/100)*f] |$

Answer (score 1):

As I noted in a comment above, this problem can be solved with Mathematica (or, of course, analytically).  The function is periodic, so a single period of the function can be transformed, and then the transforms of all periods summed.  It is convenient to begin by subtracting the average value of the function over the period, which is `2/Pi`.

```
Integrate[(Cos[ω/100] - 2/Pi), {ω, -50 Pi, 50 Pi}]
(* 0 *)
```

Mathematica quickly can integrate the central period of the function.

```
InverseFourierTransform[
    Piecewise[{{Cos[ω/100] - 2/π, -50 Pi < ω < 50 Pi}}, 0], ω, t]
(* (2 Sqrt[2] (-50 π t Cos[50 π t] + (1 - 10000 t^2) Sin[50 π t]))/
   (π^(3/2) t (-1 + 10000 t^2)) *)
```

and one would hope that it could solve for any period by

```
InverseFourierTransform[Piecewise[{{Cos[ω/100] - 2/π, 
    100 (n - 1/2) Pi < ω < 100 (n + 1/2) Pi},
    {Cos[ω/100] - 2/π, -100 (n + 1/2) Pi < ω < -100 (n - 1/2) Pi}}, 0], ω, t, 
     Assumptions -> n > 0]] // FullSimplify
```

but it seems unable to do so.  However, for specific values of `n`, for instance, `n = 1`, it readily determines

```
(* (4 Sqrt[2] Cos[100 I π t] (50 π t Cos[50 π t] + (1 - 10000 t^2) 
    Sin[50 π t]))/(π^(3/2) t (-1 + 10000 t^2))
```

from which one can generalize that the term for `n > 0` is

```
(* (4 n Sqrt[2] Cos[100 I π t] (50 π t Cos[50 π t] + (1 - 10000 t^2) 
    Sin[50 π t]))/(π^(3/2) t (-1 + 10000 t^2))
```

Thus, the sum of this term over `n > 0` plus the `n = 0` term obtained earlier, plus the delta function corresponding to the constant value `2/Pi` is the desired transform.

Comment: Thank you,but why the period of |cos(ω/100)| is 2/π ?

Comment: @Nick  It is 100 Pi.  `2/π` is the average value.

Comment: I found it 50.
Here is how:
cos(ω/100)=cos[(2πf)/100)=cos[(π/50)*f]
The period should be T=(2π/1) / (π/50)=100 and since we have absolute value we don't have negatives so the period becomes half --> T=100/2=50